# Using ASCII over UART

Tags: c, serial-port, microcontroller, uart, serial-communication

ASCII values goes from 0x00 to 0x7F. Is it possible to use the rest of values (0x80 to 0xFF) to define some macros control data flow?

Example 1:

```
#define I_AM_A_FLAG             0x80
#define GIVE_ME_A_1_BYTE_FLAG   0x81
#define GIVE_ME_SOME_TEXT       0x82
```

Master [Tx] -- GIVE_ME_A_1_BYTE_FLAG --> [Rx] Slave
Master [Rx] <------------I_AM_A_FLAG ----------- [Tx] Slave

Example 2:
Master [Tx] -- GIVE_ME_SOME_TEXT -----------------------> [Rx] Slave
Master [Rx] <------------"Hello World! I am a text\n" ----------- [Tx] Slave

Comment: Sure - so long as your UART is configured for 8 data bits.

Comment: Serial ports don't know anything about the data they transfer.  You can make the bytes mean anything you want, as long as the port can transfer them correctly.  The number of databits is configurable, 8 is a very common value.  Readable text is nice for debugging, but not so compact.  Once you start throwing in 0x80-0xff you do lose that advantage.

Answer (score 5):

Of course, as long as both communications partners agree when interpreting the bytes.

Comment: And If I am using a buffer to collect ASCII characters. What to do when I receive a flag ?

Comment: @zerocoldTUN you act accordingly to the meaning of the flag. Your comment is somewhat unclear...

Comment: When it comes to flags, data size is 1 Byte (8bits). but when it comes to text it depends on the text length: "ABC\n" is different from "ABCDEF\n". data are stored in a buffer and I need to define the buffer size (#define BUFFER_SIZE XXX). The thing is I don't know how to define the buffer size if the buffer is expecting two forms of data (ASCII and flags)

Comment: bits is bits, if you are configured to move 8 bits per character, then the interface can move any of the 256 bit patterns.  The uart/interface is no longer an issue at that point, now it is a software thing, if your software thinks the 0x80 bit means flag, then on both sides the software needs to handle those bit patterns.  ASCII is not really part of it here, those are just bit patterns as well that the software has to handle.  Write the software correctly on both sides and you wont have any issues.